# Python Pandas keep maximum 3 consecutive duplicates

Tags: python, pandas

I have this table:

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,1,2,2]
df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df.columns = ['A']
```

I want to keep maximum 3 consecutive duplicates, or keep all in case there's less than 3 (or no) duplicates.

The result should look like this:

```
list2 = [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,1,1,1,2,2]
result = pd.DataFrame(list2)
result.columns = ['A']
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with consecutive Series create by compare shifted values for not equal and cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()).head(3)
print (df1)
    A
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   3
8   4
9   1
10  1
11  1
13  2
14  2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.A.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum())
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     3
8     4
9     5
10    5
11    5
12    5
13    6
14    6
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 3):

Last us do

```
df[df.groupby(df[0].diff().ne(0).cumsum())[0].cumcount()<3]
    0
0   1
1   1
2   2
3   2
4   3
5   3
6   3
8   4
9   1
10  1
11  1
13  2
14  2
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a great way to do this

Comment: @CyrilYU yw :-) happy coding ~

Comment: One more thing to ask: if data type of column 0 is string, what can I use instead of .diff() ?

Comment: @CyrilYU df[df.groupby(df[0].ne(df[0].shift()).cumsum())[0].cumcount()<3]

Comment: Oh with .shift() and .ne()? I think I found it

Comment: @CyrilYU yes :-) shift for type str and object ~

Answer (score 1):

Solving with [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) which groups only consecutive duplicates , then slicing 3 elements:

```
import itertools

pd.Series(itertools.chain.from_iterable([*g][:3] for i,g in itertools.groupby(df['A'])))
```

---

```
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     3
5     3
6     3
7     4
8     1
9     1
10    1
11    2
12    2
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. Is it possible to use itertools to filter the original df into the result df? The original df has other columns.